# how to use reflection on a master page?

Tags: asp.net, reflection, user-controls, master-pages

I want to invoke a masterPage's method from a inner user-control 
(user control inside another user-control).

The thing is that the inner control doesn't know the type of its master page at compile time.
How can I use reflection on the master page to find a specific method and invoke it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using reflection you could solve this by using an [interface](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson13.aspx). Define an interface for whatever the user control needs are and then implement it in the master page.

Comment: what if the master page weren't available for me?

Comment: Then something very serious would be wrong and neither reflection nor interfaces could help you.